# How to get raw validationmessages in ValidationMessageFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I got an asp.net mvc4 application where I'd like to retrieve only the exact error string of validationmessagefor and not the span tag, classes etc.

Currently the following is being returned from ValidationMessageFor:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Password">
     <span class="" for="Password" generated="true">The Password field is required.</span>
</span>
```

I would like to only have returned: **The Password field is required.**

It's because I need to insert the exact value into another element attribute (so I can't use the HTML tags).

Essentially I need a custom ValidationMessageFor html helper that only returns the error message itself.

How would I do this?

Comment: could you be more specific ? where did you like to parse this messages? On server-side or client-side. Show what you already tried.

Comment: @DawidDziadkiewicz

Sorry for the bad explanation - I've updated my question.
Also it'd have to be Client-Side

Answer (score 2):

Any error messages are a part of your `ModelState`.

For example, if you have a required field FirstName you can get the error message like this:

```
ModelState["FirstName"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage
```

In this case, you expect that there is only one error. This property returns 'The FirstName field is required'.

You can access `ModelState` from your controller or from your view by using `ViewDate.ModelState`.

`ModelState` is of type `ModelStateDictionary` which is an `IDictionary<string, ModelState>`. It only has an indexer property of type string. Because of this you can't access it by using `ModelState[p => p.Property]`. However, you can easily create an extension method that helps you with this:

```
public static class ModelStateExtension
{
    public static ModelState For<TModel>(this ModelStateDictionary dictionary,
        Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression)
    {
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        return dictionary[propertyName];
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string errorMessage = ModelState.For<Person>(p => p.FirstName).Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
```

If you want, you can let the extension method return the `ErrorMessage` for the first error directly instead of the `ModelState.`

Comment: Is it possible to use lambda expressions in the modelstate? As in ModelState(m => m.Password).Errors[0].ErrorMessage ?

Answer (score 0):

To access errors you should use *ModelState.Errors* property. It contains

> ModelErrorCollection

whith is a collection of

> ModelError

Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

You can create your own helper then, and access those messagess on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific property you can use

```
 ViewData.ModelState["Password"].Errors
```